# Card Slide using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to do a card slider with slide bar using JavaScript without any framework and library. It should be able to slide through the section. I have tried this code, but it doesn't work for me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can help me, please?

Note: I didn't manage to do slide through the section here

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="slider-container">
            <div class="card" id="content1" class="active">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="image/Screenshot_20230126_035745.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <div class="price">15€</div>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" id="content2">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="image/Screenshot_20230126_035745.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <div class="price">15€</div>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" id="content3">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="image/Screenshot_20230126_035745.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <div class="price">15€</div>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" id="content4">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="image/Screenshot_20230126_035745.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <div class="price">15€</div>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="dot-container">
            <button onclick="dot(1)"></button>
            <button onclick="dot(2)"></button>
            <button onclick="dot(3)"></button>
            <button onclick="dot(4)"></button>
        </div>

        <button id="prev" onclick="prev()"> &lt; </button>
        <button id="next" onclick="next()"> &gt; </button>
    </div>
```

```
const dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot-container button");
const slider = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-container .card");

let i = 0; // current slide
let j = 4; // total slides

function next() {
    document.getElementById("content" + (i + 1)).classList.remove("active");
    i = (j + i + 1) % j;
    document.getElementById("content" + (i + 1)).classList.add("active");
    indicator(i + 1);
}

function prev() {
    document.getElementById("content" + (i + 1)).classList.remove("active");
    i = (j + i - 1) % j;
    document.getElementById("content" + (i + 1)).classList.add("active");
    indicator(i + 1);
}

function indicator(num) {
    dots.forEach(function (dot) {
        dot.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    });
    document.querySelector(".dot-container button:nth-child(" + num + ")").style.backgroundColor = "#076bb8";
}

function dot(index) {
    slider.forEach(function (image) {
        image.classList.remove("active");
    });
    document.getElementById("content" + index).classList.add("active");
    i = index - 1;
    indicator(index);
}
```

Comment: I created a quick snippet with generic CSS setting .card to display none and .card.active to display block and it does work. But a problem that you have is your first div has TWO class arguments. You will need to combine them to say **class="card active"**